# Changing the number of parameters and unifying

Tags: prolog

I'm having a problem with getting the right output. I get my result as you can see in the trace. But i cant figure out hot to stop it at the certain point. It should calculate what the formula said and simply write the result to the list and decrement D and repeat that until it hits 0 and not do the 0.

```
t(R, L) :- t(R, R, L).

t(D, R, [Ti|L]) :- D >= 1, !,
                 Ti is D * ((D + 1) / 2),
                 D1 is D - 1,
                 t(D1, R, [Ti|L]).
```

the input is t(2, L).

```
Call: (8) t(2, _1804) ? creep
Call: (9) t(2, 2, _1804) ? creep
Call: (10) 2>=1 ? creep
Exit: (10) 2>=1 ? creep
Call: (10) _2052 is 2*((2+1)/2) ? creep
Exit: (10) 3.0 is 2*((2+1)/2) ? creep
Call: (10) _2064 is 2+ -1 ? creep
Exit: (10) 1 is 2+ -1 ? creep
Call: (10) t(1, 2, [3.0|_1804]) ? creep
Call: (11) 1>=1 ? creep
Exit: (11) 1>=1 ? creep
Call: (11) _2088 is 1*((1+1)/2) ? creep
Exit: (11) 1 is 1*((1+1)/2) ? creep
Call: (11) _2094 is 1+ -1 ? creep
Exit: (11) 0 is 1+ -1 ? creep
Call: (11) t(0, 2, [1, 3.0|_1804]) ? creep
Call: (12) 0>=1 ? creep
Fail: (12) 0>=1 ? creep
**Fail: (11) t(0, 2, [1, 3.0|_1804]) ? creep**
Fail: (10) t(1, 2, [3.0|_1804]) ? creep
Fail: (9) t(2, 2, _1804) ? creep
Fail: (8) t(2, _1804) ? creep
false.
```

The output should be L=[1,3] based on this formula **Ti is D * ((D + 1) / 2)** as is is on the marked line in the trace but its not. It should stop when it hits D=0 but it does not.

I tried all of therse to stop it by creating a case for 0 but it doesnt work.

```
t(0, []) :- !.
t(0, _, _) :- !.
t(_, _, R, L) :- R < 1, !.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never told Prolog what to do in case `D=0`. So Prolog keeps decrementing `D` until `D >= 1` no longer succeeds, and then that means that you reached a point of "*failure*". Prolog will then start backtracking until it finds a backtracking point, or here, it will unwind the entire call stack, and report failure.

Even if you manage to implement a stop condition, this is *not* sufficient, since in your predicate, you use `[Ti|L]` as parameter, and recursively you call with `[Ti|L]`. This means that a recursive call will aim to set an element in the list, the *same* element (!), and if the values are different, this again will result in a failure.

Since you built the list right-to-left, you can use an accumulator, that starts with an empty list, and each time prepend the element to the list in the recursive call. The stop condition then unifies the accumulator with the result.

```
t(R, L) :-
    t(R, [], L).

t(0, R, R).
t(D, L, R) :-
    D >= 1, !,
    Ti is D * ((D + 1) / 2),
    D1 is D - 1,
    t(D1, [Ti|L], R).
```

This then yields the expected:

```
?- t(2, L).
L = [1, 3.0] ;
false.
```

Note however that you can make the above more efficient, by working left-to-right, and use an accumulator that sums up the indices.

For example:

```
t(N, R) :-
    t(1, 1, N, R).

t(I, _, N, []) :-
    I > N.
t(I, A, N, [A|T]) :-
    I =< N,
    I1 is I+1,
    A1 is A + I1,
    t(I1, A1, N, T).
```